# Bash/Readline vi line editing mode doesn't work in Screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, readline, inputrc

I have `set -o vi` in my ~/.profile, and it works fine on the regular console and under Tmux. But when I run Screen, if I press Escape or ^[, I get a visual bell, the next key I press seems to get eaten by something, and then I'm still in Insert mode in Bash. How do I tell Screen to pass the ^[ on to the shell? (Or, alternately, is there something I can do in .inputrc that will allow me to use a different key combo to enter command mode?)

Comment: `screen` doesn't read `.profile` for its subshells.

Comment: Good Lord... thank you. Now to remove my palm from my face...

Comment: Pleased to be of service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to vi-editing mode via `set -o vi` in your .profile, this won't be passed into the screen's shell, because the screen's shell isn't a login shell and thus doesn't read .profile.

You need to put the following into your .inputrc

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm embarrassed that the answer was so stupid. For any lurkers, I'll add that you can also set in screenrc `shell -$SHELL`, which makes screen subshells be full login shells.